# MYSQL - Short money values (example $2.50) column from low to high, where filed type = VARCHAR

Tags: mysql

i use phpmyadmin.
I have a **table "Prices"** with a **column "price_usd"**. The **column field type = VARCHAR**, reason is that sometimes i add values like "*Pending*"

**The question:**
Is there any way, to 
ORDER BY FIELD price_usd DESC

 and not have results like: 
$10.55
$15.20
$55.00
$9.20

 BUT:
$9.20
$10.55
$15.20
$55.00
*Might be a way to query the column AS DECIMAL? I mean just view it as DECIMAL and not actually change the field type.

Comment: If you want good performance, no. If you just want the convenience and don't need speed, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can convert the values to numbers, by getting rid of the leading dollar sign.  In MySQL, you can do the conversion just by treating the result as a number.  I often add zero:

```
order by replace(price, '$', '') + 0
```

Note that strings such as `'PENDING'` will be converted to `0`.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good practice. The info "Pending" should be done not in the database value, but in your application. Set your "price_usd" to allow `NULL` value. Then in your application, when you read this data, if price_usd is `NULL`, then you display it as "Pending".

That's how it should work best.

Hope this helps.